# how to replace elements of pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series object S, some elements are name-value pairs, like
a-12
b-23
c-42
d-25
...

some are just 
a
b
c
d
....

so on, what I need to do is to get this into Json format like:

```
{Name:a,Value:12}
{Name:b,Value:23}
{Name:c,Value:42}
{Name:d,Value:25}
```

...

If only a, b, c, d, not pairs,  Values is NaN.

I used str.split("-") function to separate the pairs, for non pairs this would produce NaN for the value part.

I wonder if I can put them together like

```
result=[{"Name": S.str.split("-").str.get(0),"Value": S.str.split("-").str.get(1)}]
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you want to start from a series object at all? How did you get there? It might be easier to think of a series as an indexed list, or as a dictionary, in which case you can see that it gets confusing if the items are of different types.

FWIW, you can convert a series directly to json or dict with `myseries.to_json()` or `myseries.to_dict()`

Did you try that?

Comment: no, but thanks, I don't think I made the question clear, but I posted again, and got a good answer. thanks again.

Comment: in that case, you should delete this question.